# Javascript arrays: How to remove the all matched elements which are contained in another array

Tags: arrays

I have 2 javascript arrays which are `a`, `b` and I want to remove the common elements from the array `a`.

Can you please help on this.

```
var a = [{
    name: 'java',
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    name: 'php',
    id: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'ruby',
    id: '3'
  },
  {
    name: 'phyton',
    id: '4'
  }

];
var b = [{
    name: 'java',
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    name: 'php',
    id: '2'
  }


];
```

Comment: The ids are the same for both? java is always 1 and php always 2 and so on?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a simple filter operation. I'd take the ids from b into an array, then filter by those elements

```js
var a = [{
    name: 'java',
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    name: 'php',
    id: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'ruby',
    id: '3'
  },
  {
    name: 'phyton',
    id: '4'
  }
];
var b = [{
    name: 'java',
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    name: 'php',
    id: '2'
  }
];

const exists = b.map(e => e.id);
const res = a.filter(e => !exists.includes(e.id));
console.log(res);
```